# Joint Mac and PC backup

Tags: backup

Does anyone know of automatic backup software (client) that creates backups that:

1. **both** a Mac and a PC can jointly access
2. provides a **recover/restore** facility for easy restoration of latest file
3. can schedule automatic incremental backups

Comment: What's your target backup media? Tape, disk etc??

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about backup software for your home computers, try CrashPlan ( http://www.crashplan.com/ ).  I believe it does everything you want it to do (I've done cross-platform restores, etc.) and the online backup (if you want it) is cheap.

Comment: Thanks - I'm looking at that. It does not seem to allow backup to a Network drive, which is a pity.